# Update form value with PHP and JS

Tags: javascript, php

I have a `foreach` statement that returns some text from the current DB and I'm attempting to populate a another field based on that that rows ID. I made a button with an `onclick` function but every time I click the echoed button it fills in the same ID every time. Any recommendations so that the echoed click returns the ID of that echoed row?

```
$a = 0;

                    foreach ($announcement as $row) { //Displays title, startDate, endDate from announcement table from database 

                    $x[$a] = $row["announcementID"];
                    ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function changeText(value) {
                             document.getElementById('title').value = <?php echo(json_encode($row["announcementID"])); ?> ;
                        }
                    </script>
                    <?php
                    //echo "<h2 style=width:auto;padding:8px;margin-top:-30px;font-size:18px;><a style=text-decoration:none;color:#c4572f; >".$row["title"]."</a></h2><br>";
                    //echo "<p style=padding-top:10px;>".$row["content"]."</p><br>";
                    //echo "<p style=font-size:10px;>Posted: ".$row["startDate"]."</p><br>";
                    echo "<input type=button onclick=changeText".$x[$a]."() value=Edit>";
                    echo "<p style=font-size:10px;>Posted: ".$x[$a]."</p> <br />";
                    //echo "<h5 style=line-height:2px;margin-top:-15px;><p>_____________________________________</p></h5><br>";



}
```

Comment: Don't you need a `while` loop and put `foreach` between it?

Comment: If your foreach loop is creating multiple JS functions which are all named changeText(), then you are redefining the same function over and over. You can only define the function once.

Comment: Ahh I see, Ill work on it and post an update when i get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need to define a new function to deal with this each time, you can pass the element into the function in your onclick call and get the id.

in your js script

```
 <script>
  function changeText(elem) {
      document.getElementById('title').value = elem.id;
  }
 </script>
```

your php

```
foreach ($announcement as $row) { //Displays title, startDate, endDate from announcement table from database 

    $x[$a] = $row["announcementID"];
    //echo "<h2 style=width:auto;padding:8px;margin-top:-30px;font-size:18px;><a style=text-decoration:none;color:#c4572f; >".$row["title"]."</a></h2><br>";
    //echo "<p style=padding-top:10px;>".$row["content"]."</p><br>";
    //echo "<p style=font-size:10px;>Posted: ".$row["startDate"]."</p><br>";
    echo '<input id="'.$x[$a].'" type=button onclick="changeText(this)" value="Edit">';
    echo "<p style=font-size:10px;>Posted: ".$x[$a]."</p> <br />";
    //echo "<h5 style=line-height:2px;margin-top:-15px;><p>_____________________________________</p></h5><br>";

}
```

Comment: I edited my post down to the bare bones. I'm confused as to how I'd implement your solution with my code.

Comment: what is in this `echo(json_encode($row["announcementID"]))`?

Comment: Thats supposed to echo the id stored in the DB of the row the button is attached to.

Comment: ok then as above, just to be clear, the code in the script tag gets added once....it will handle the onclick event on the elements. i'm going to tidy a small bit as well

Comment: Perfect! Worked great, just what I was looking for.